# about UI programming on Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I was just wondering if theres any resource that helps with or explains UI programming on the Android. I am looking for something thats similar to the UI programming of iOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials available from the Android Developer are [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html), the Technical Resource article list for [Layouts/Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=layout) and the Developer Guide's [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) article and sub articles.

Comment: Which is to say not a lot, for instance - is there anywhere a reference of all the xml elemnts and attributes and their uses ?  

I come from a Visual Studio/xaml background and I am having a hard time with java/eclipse

I would like to find something that shows me that android UIs can be as easy to make as silverlight.

Comment: Yes there is, [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is a super class of all widgets every xml attribute and description is in there or the base class with their related information. The xml value definitions are in the [open source repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/attrs.xml;h=6370696708a2b7ecb561015629801bd380fe486a;hb=refs/heads/master) (start under `View package class attributes`, if you're using Eclipse with ADT all the enumeration values are already there with content assist.